# Se me hace complicado este problema en la parte del promedio por mes y año ya que en la tabla employees no hay un atributo ventas

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

#Consulta basado en el código país, este debe devolver el listado de empleados con los montos de ventas promedios por mes y año. Donde las ordenes no estén en estatus “Cancelled”[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT OF.officeCode
    ,OF.country
    ,E.firstName
    ,E.lastName
    ,SUM(C.salesRepEmployeeNumber) AS 'PROMEDIO'
FROM offices AS OF
JOIN employees AS E ON OF.officeCode = E.officeCode
JOIN customers AS C ON E.employeeNumber = C.salesRepEmployeeNumber
JOIN orders AS O ON C.customerNumber = O.customerNumber
JOIN orderdetails AS OD ON O.orderNumber = OD.orderNumber
WHERE O.STATUS NOT LIKE "Cancelled"
```

Comment: No hay ventas, pero existe la tabla Orders que te indica justamente las órdenes (ventas) que se han hecho y oh! tiene una relación con Customers que a su vez contiene una columna que indica qué Empleado le ha realizado una venta y no sé si es MySQL o SQL Server (detalla además agrega tus intentos), pero seguro que con un COUNT, SUM y unos JOINS lo completas ;)

Comment: SELECT OF.officeCode, OF.country, E.firstName, E.lastName ,SUM(C.salesRepEmployeeNumber) AS 'PROMEDIO' 
FROM offices AS OF
JOIN employees AS E ON OF.officeCode=E.officeCode
JOIN customers AS C ON E.employeeNumber=C.salesRepEmployeeNumber
JOIN orders AS O ON C.customerNumber=O.customerNumber
JOIN orderdetails AS OD ON O.orderNumber=OD.orderNumber
WHERE O.status NOT LIKE "Cancelled"

Comment: Esto es lo que he avanzado pero aún no se como sacar el promedio de su total por mes y año

Comment: Se puede editar la pregunta para poner el código ahí y que sea más claro

Comment: ¿Cómo calcularías el promedio? ¿Sería el importe total de ventas entre el número de ventas? ¿El importe promedio por artículo? Vas bien, pero hay que definir un poco mejor la pregunta.

Comment: Por qué existe una relación entre `empleado` y `cliente`? Es idea mía o pierde trazablidad? Qué ocurre si el empleado se va? Se le cambia el `repNumbe`r al cliente? De ser así, cómo voy a obtener todas las ventas por empleado para ese cliente si el departamento de venta tiene alta rotación? La relación debería ser entre `empleado` y `orden`, no?

Comment: @Arriel Por el tipo de problema, es probable que la base de datos sea de ejemplo y no algún sistema productivo. Por lo tanto, no creo que sea relevante corregir su diseño.

Answer (score 0):

soy nuevo en estoy, pero si lo que quieres es ordenarlas por fecha habría que meter un COUNT para las ventas (Orders) o COUNT DISTINC para omitir duplicados, y un GROUP BY para agrupar por fechas.
Esto, a continuación de lo que ya tienes escrito.

No sé si te he ayudado, lo he intentado.